# access query param in angular and IE8

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access query params in an angular way but cannot get it to work in IE8 - using Angular v1.0.3.

I am setting up html5 mode:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function($locationProvider) {
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});
```

And in my directive:

```
scope.location = $location;
scope.$watch('location.search()', function() {
    console.log($location.search());
}, true);
```

Works fine in normal browsers but not sure how to fix IE8 - google posts are either unclear or old.

Answer (score 0):

Ah - hashbang mode: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.$location

```
http://localhost/#?id=blah instead of http://localhost/?id=blah
```